# Many-to-many relationships with several fields in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have the following model:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    passenger = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    shared_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

Each `Trip` can have a `driver` alone, or a `driver` with several `passenger`. For each `passenger` the `driver` can set the percentage of the `trip_cost` each passenger is going to pay.

What I need is to have:

1. the field `passenger` to be listing all `Users`
2. several `passenger` + `shared_cost` for each `Trip`.

I guess I should use Many-to-many but I cannot make it work. Also when I try to set the passenger to `models.ForeignKey(User)`, I get an error.

Any help or direction highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `related_name` when refer to same models using 2 fields.

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driver')
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    passenger = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='passenger')
    shared_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```